# Unable to fetch records based on datefield=currentdate in jhipster

Tags: mysql, rest, spring-boot, jpa, jhipster

i have been working on a project in jhipster. And as of now i struggling with a rest api to fetch records of a table(appointments) of currentdate. the code doesn't have errors but doesn't outputs anything.(i have data in my table too).

`GET  /appointmentspending : get all the appointments with status pending.

```
 @param filter the filter of the request
 @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of appointments in body
 /
@GetMapping("/searchappointment")
@Timed
public List<Appointment> getAllAppointmentOfToday(@RequestParam(required = false) String filter) {
     //LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    // System.out.println("localDate");
  log.debug("REST request to get all Appointments with status pending");
          //LocalDate date = '2019-02-06'

    return StreamSupport
            .stream(appointmentRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .filter(appointment -> appointment.getLastvisited() == LocalDate.now())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you cannot compare objects with `==`, since that compares the Object references, and not the actual values of the object. It is similar to comparing two pointers in C and C++.

In order to compare their values, use the `equals` method of the objects.

So your code would look the following way now:

```
@GetMapping("/searchappointment")
@Timed
public List<Appointment> getAllAppointmentOfToday(@RequestParam(required = false) String filter) {
    // LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    // System.out.println("localDate");
    log.debug("REST request to get all Appointments with status pending");
    // LocalDate date = '2019-02-06'

    return StreamSupport
            .stream(appointmentRepository.findAll().spliterator(), false)
            .filter(appointment -> appointment.getLastvisited().equals(LocalDate.now()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}`
```